# Execute code after rendering all images in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to do some code execution after all images are loaded (need the set scroll  in a specific position). I use nextTik() but Codes are processed before loading images . We also can't use mounted and created and methods like this because codes should be executed after clicking on a button.
is there any method or trick?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the **[load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load)** event on each image to check if all images have been loaded.

example: https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/e5bd86k6/1/

```
<div id="app">
  <img @load="handleLoad"  @error="handleLoad" v-for="i in 10" :src="`https://picsum.photos/${Math.random()*300}/700/?random`"/>
</div>
```

Javascript

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    imgLoaded: 0
  },
  methods: {
    handleLoad: function(todo){
        this.imgLoaded++;
      if(this.imgLoaded === 10) {
        alert('all image loaded')   
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: inteligent way, but image pathes are fetched from database and i don't know how many images exists.

Comment: @MostafaAbedi what's your data structure? if you can render it, surely you can count it dynamically

Comment: ok! let me describe more. it's a bunch of palceholders  in a page and we fetches them from database, some of this placeholders may hold voice and some others video and some images, after loading all medias i should set scroll position.

Comment: @MostafaAbedi hi. I realized that `load` won't trigger if the image fails to load. (image 404). To fix add, you may that ` @error="handleLoad"` for listening to the `error` event

Answer (score 1):

Based on  ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/50481269 [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50481269)) answer I did something like this:

```
    <img class="card-img-top" :src=" 'images/' + (data.src || 'image-default.png') " 
    :alt="data.alt" @load="handleImagesLoad" @error="handleImagesLoad">
```

(@load and @error on each image on my page) and

```
   handleImagesLoad: function($event){
       var images = $('img:not([loaded])');
       var target = $($event.target);
       $(target).attr('loaded', true);

       if(images.length <= 1){
           $('#preloader').fadeOut();
       }
   },
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach for a component having both "static" images and an an arbitray number of images fetched from database :

- Append two items to the component data: 'imgsLength' and 'loadedImgsLength'
- Append a 'load' event handler to every img element, that increments 'loadedImgsLength'
- After all fetched data are loaded, set 'imgsLength' to the number of all img elements

So, you know that all images are loaded when 'loadedImgsLength' > 0 and 'loadedImgsLength' == 'imgsLength'

**In this exemple, my component won't be visible until all images are loaded:**

```
<template>
   <div v-show="ready" ref="myComponent">
      ...
      <img src="..." @load="loadedImgsLength++" />  (static image)
      ...
      <img v-for="img in fetchedImg" @load="loadedImgsLength++" />  (dynamic images)
   </div>
</template>

<script>
...
   data(){
      return {
         ...,
         imgsLength : 0,
         loadedImgsLength: 0,
         ...,
      }
   },

   computed: {
     ready(){
        return (this.loadedImgsLength > 0 && this.loadedImgsLength == this.imgsLength)
      }
   },

   async created(){
      ... fetch all data
      this.$nextTick(() => this.$nextTick(this.imgsLength = this.$refs.myComponent.getElementsByTagName("img").length))
   }
```